# mysql looping on values in a procedure

Tags: mysql, function, stored-procedures

I am writing a procedure like below:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS procedure1;

CREATE PROCEDURE procedure1()
BEGIN

declare n int default 0;
declare i int default 0; 

DECLARE a int(11);
DECLARE b varChar(50);

DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT column_y from table_y;

DECLARE cur2 CURSOR FOR select column_x from table_x ;

set n =884;
set i=0;
OPEN cur1;
Fetch cur1 into a;
OPEN cur2;
Fetch cur2 into b;

while a>0 DO
  while b>0 do
    call function_x(a,b);
    b--;
  a--;


close cur1;
END;
```

Now I want first loop over all the values in the var a and inside that loop I want to loop over all the values in var b.
The problem is the variables a and b are not intergers values which can be decremented, they are a unique number and to be passed to function function_x()

Does any one know how to write for each value kind of loop?

Comment: This might help: http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2005/10/nesting-mysql-cursor-loops.html

Comment: This link really helped . Thankyou !